# Show or hide button based on textbox's value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I will hide the "login" button if both textbox (id and pass) is not filled.
Else I will show it.

inside the script block:

```
protected void checkField(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (id.Text == "" || pass.Text == "")
    {
        logbutton.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (id.Text != "" && pass.Text != "")
        logbutton.Visible = true;
}
```

inside the form block i have two text box, one is for ID, one is for Password
Everytime I on blur or on focus (tried all of them) any of these two I will call the  function above

But I have never seen the "login" button showing / disappearing after modifying the two text boxes.

Comment: How are you even calling this event handler? Do you expect your client-side code to call the server-side method without a postback? Post some more _relevant_ code. =)

Comment: Can you confirm exactly how you are calling the above function? It's server-side code, so would only happen on a post-back of the page (not something that I think is going to happen when filling in the textboxes)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic prevents hiding the button. Try removing the second elseif condition

```
 protected void checkField(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (id.Text == "" || pass.Text == "")
        {
            logbutton.Visible = false;
        }
        else
            logbutton.Visible = true;
    }
```

Also, make sure that the login button's visible property is initially set to FALSE, and set autopostback property for both the UserID and Paasword Textboxes to TRUE